# How to map IQueryable from multiple tables in a LINQ query expression?

Tags: linq, automapper

Is it possible to use AutoMapper to avoid the manual mapping bellow that gets executes a join on 2 tables in the select statement?

```
 private IQueryable<HHDrawingNumber> GetDrawingNumbers()
    {
        var drawingNumbers = from dn in _unitOfWork.DrawingNumbers.Get()
            join ld in _unitOfWork.CfgLocDrawing.Get() on dn.LocDrawingNum equals ld.DrawingsId
            join ar in _unitOfWork.AssetReg.Get() on dn.AssetId equals ar.LastData
            select new HHDrawingNumber
            {
                TagNumber = dn.TagNumber ?? string.Empty,
                DrawingsId = ld.DrawingsId,
                DrawingsCode = ld.DrawingsCode ?? string.Empty,
                DrawingsDescription = ld.DrawingsDescription ?? string.Empty
            };
        return drawingNumbers;
    }
```

Comment: Yes. You need in your source object the FK properties. DrawingNumber seems the source, CfgLocDrawing and AssetReg the FK-s.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu, right, so if I understand correctly, I will need to change the db schema?

Comment: I think you already have the FK-s, you just need the FK object references in your EF classes.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu, sorry, I am new to AutoMapper, how would the Map method look like in this case, it is not clear for me.

Comment: The docs are [here](http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Queryable-Extensions.html) and the tests [here](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/tree/master/src/IntegrationTests).

Comment: @lucianBargaonu thanks! Much appreciated!